# Do we need NodeJs for running react app on server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asp.net-core

I have .net Core 2.2 project work with react,

I'm about to finish the project, I have a question I was wondering before I published.

Do I need to have NodeJs installed on the server for React to work?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. If you're just going to serve static files (HTML, CSS, JS), then no; all you need is a web server. If you want to do server-side rendering, though, *something* will have to do that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I used webpack and babeljs for React to work, so I guess I don't need to install nodejs on the server side, right?

Comment: Again, it depends; SSR will need webpack and Babel *on the server* to work.

Comment: @Avoraa, this answer will solve your confusion.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328074/deploy-asp-net-react-template-without-nodejs-dependency-on-iis-server

Comment: @MalikAwan I'm not sure if it's a server-side pre-rendering, obviously. In short, I take and process the data. I am updating, deleting, reading and adding. I use axios as a library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you build the React project, you will end up with `build` directory with static `html`, `css` and `js` files. If you put these into `htdocs` directory or whatever directory (based on server which are you using, probably Apache or Nginx), it will serve it without any additional things like Node, etc

Comment: I had to use react on part of my project, so I used babel with webpack to run it on .net core. I will publish the application on windows hosting. NodeJs required?

Comment: @Avoraa what exactly does your application do?

Comment: In short, I take data through web api, and distribute it to subcomponents. I do update, add, delete and read. I use react hooks as scaffold structure.

Comment: @Avoraa well, I think that if you build it, you won't need node.js. Only put result to correct directory and it should do the work :)

Answer (score 3):

React is a Front End Javascript library, There is no requirement for any specific server language. The work React does is in the browser.

Facebook was built with PHP and large parts of it used react with PHP as back-end.